# Showing connected adapter

Tags: vb.net, ip

I want to show only connected adapter with ip address from one computer. Currently i have this code but it show loopback adapter as well. How can i show only operation status up only to be displayed?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Interfaces As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
    Dim myAdapterProps As IPInterfaceProperties = Nothing
    Dim myGateways As GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection = Nothing

    For Each adapter In Interfaces
        TextBox1.AppendText("" & Environment.NewLine)
        If adapter.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback Then
            Continue For
        End If
        TextBox1.AppendText(adapter.Name & Environment.NewLine)
        TextBox1.AppendText(adapter.Description & Environment.NewLine)
        myAdapterProps = adapter.GetIPProperties
        myGateways = myAdapterProps.GatewayAddresses
        Dim IPInfo As UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection = adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
        Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()

        For Each IPAddressInfo As UnicastIPAddressInformation In IPInfo

            TextBox1.AppendText("IP Address : " & IPAddressInfo.Address.ToString & Environment.NewLine)

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. If you want to see only adapters that have the status **up**, then exclude all adapters that does not have this status in your `continue`branch:

```
adapter.OperationalStatus <> OperationalStatus.Up
```

If you want additionally to remove the Teredo adapter from the output, then exclude the adapter if the name contains the word *Teredo*:

```
adapter.Name.Contains("Teredo")
```

The modified code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim Interfaces As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
Dim myAdapterProps As IPInterfaceProperties = Nothing
Dim myGateways As GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection = Nothing

For Each adapter In Interfaces
    TextBox1.AppendText("" & Environment.NewLine)
    If adapter.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback _
    or adapter.OperationalStatus <> OperationalStatus.Up _
    or adapter.Name.Contains("Teredo") Then
        Continue For
    End If
    TextBox1.AppendText(adapter.Name & Environment.NewLine)
    TextBox1.AppendText(adapter.Description & Environment.NewLine)
    myAdapterProps = adapter.GetIPProperties
    myGateways = myAdapterProps.GatewayAddresses
    Dim IPInfo As UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection = adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
    Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()

    For Each IPAddressInfo As UnicastIPAddressInformation In IPInfo
        TextBox1.AppendText("IP Address : " & IPAddressInfo.Address.ToString & Environment.NewLine)
    Next IPAddressInfo
Next

End Sub
```

This should show the non local up-adapters and no *Teredo* adapters only.

Comment: thx a lot!! it works. one thing i want to ask.

Local Area Connection
Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
IP Address : fe80::356c:885f:69a4:a0f4%11
IP Address : 10.67.102.187
Local Area Connection* 34
Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
IP Address : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:891:36d3:f5bc:9944
IP Address : fe80::891:36d3:f5bc:9944%63

what is the second connection (Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface ) ? in my network sharing center dont have that kind of connection

Comment: Teredo is a virtual adapter for IPv6 tunneling. It can't be used directly, so you will not see it in your adapters list in windows. For a detailed explanation have a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling).

Comment: can i remove it from showing  inside the connection list?

Comment: Yes - in the continue branch check for the adapter name and skip it if it's called *Teredo*. I have updated the source in my answer to exclude the Teredo adapter too.

Comment: I notice something. Not sure if its only me or what.. Few time run the code, the teredo adapter is not displayed but when i close and open up back, the teredo adapter shown

Comment: just want to know. is it possible to take the ipv4 address from the textbox into a combobox?

Comment: Yes, instead of the TextBox control use `ComboBox.Items.Add(...)`.

Comment: both ipv6 and ipv4 showed. can i limit so that the combobox only show ipv4?

Comment: Yes, use the properties of the [IPAddress class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or don't output every property. You can filter the addresses (using regex on the output, orusing properties).